# Youtube videos taking many page refreshes to load, and freezing when pausing

Tags: video, freeze, youtube

I am running a cunstom build desktop with the latest version of Windows 10 and recently, maybe a week ago, youtube started acting weird.
When I open up a video, the content of the page loads fine and quickly, but the video itself will almost always not load and instead buffer indefinitely, with the spinning circle and all. It will often take multiple (from 5 up to 10 or more!) refreshes of the page to get the video to play, and when it finaly loads it does so quickly and without trouble.

Another problem that started at the same time, and which I suspect may be related to the previous one for that reason, is that once I got a video to play, more often than not if I pause the video it will be stuck like that and will not unpause with subsequent presses of the pause button.

To top it all off, it's kind of inconsistent whether or not all of that will happen. On some occasions everything will be fine, but most of the time the two problems I've described will occur.
One thing of note is that when an add is inserted before the video starts, then it will always play just fine, and upon skipping the add or waiting for it to end, the video will also allways load and play just fine, as well as pause and unpause normaly.

Did anyone get the same issue? If so, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: What computer, OS, browser?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention it. I'm running the latest version of Windows 10 on a cunstom built desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, on the day I'm posting this answer, I happened to make an upgrade to my home internet network by running an ethernet cable directly between my home router and my computer. Before that, since my router and my computer are on different floor levels, I had my computer connected to a device that carries the internet connection through the wall and into the computer. But since it was extremely slow and unrelyable, and just a pain in the backside, I decided to invest in a long cable to plug directly into the router. Eversince then, the issue has completely disapeared, so it seems it was just a problem with the quality of my internet connection.